# How render Input fields dynamically based on position set in database with EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a input fields types stored in the database with their position set by user. So eg FirstName, textbox 1, lastname textbox 2. This position can be change. I want to render a view showing the input elements on their position in the database. This is  the data database I get from the database`formular:

```
   [ { FormularID: 187,                                                                                                                                                                                                
       CampaignID: 13,                                                                                                                                                                                                 
       FormLabel: 'Title',                                                                                                                                                                                             
       InputType: 'textbox',                                                                                                                                                                                           
       InputDetails: '',                                                                                                                                                                                               
       InputPosition: 1 },  
     FormularID: 188,                                                                                                                                                                                                
       CampaignID: 13,                                                                                                                                                                                                 
       FormLabel: 'DATE OF BIRTH',                                                                                                                                                                                             
       InputType: 'DATE',                                                                                                                                                                                           
       InputDetails: '',                                                                                                                                                                                               
       InputPosition: 2 },                                                                                                                                                                                             
     { FormularID: 189,                                                                                                                                                                                                
       CampaignID: 13,                                                                                                                                                                                                 
       FormLabel: 'First Name',                                                                                                                                                                                        
       InputType: 'textbox',                                                                                                                                                                                           
       InputDetails: '',                                                                                                                                                                                               
       InputPosition: 0 } ] }    `
Now in my view i have tried this but it doesn't arrange based on the position set.

    <% for(var i in templateData.formular){ %>
    <% if(templateData.formular[i].InputPosition==i){ %>
        <% if(templateData.formular[i].InputType=='textbox'){ %>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3"><%=templateData.formular[i].FormLabel + i %></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3">
            </div>
        <% } %>
<% if(templateData.formular[i].InputType=='date'){ %>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"><%=templateData.formular[i].FormLabel%></label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3">
            </div>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
```

So if the user decides to set firstname as 2 and tile as 1 and dateofbirth as 0. I want the view to render the fields in that order.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by modifying the the above structure like this

```
<% for(var i=0; i< templateData.formular.length; i++){ %>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3"><%=templateData.formular[i].FormLabel %></label>
        <input type="<%=templateData.formular[i].InputType %>"class="form-control" id="inputEmail3">
        </div>
<% } %>
```

and then in the backend when I read from the the database I orderBy InputPosition through my database and get the data ordered in ascending order.
So however the user decides to position the elements , they are arranged in that order 1-2-3 ---n and render that order.